# Does Enum.GetValues() use reflection?

Tags: c#, .net

Does Enum.GetValues() use reflection?

I don't think it would, since at compile time it should be able to grab the list of possible values and store them. But I don't know if that's what it actually does.

Comment: [You tell me.](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/enum.cs,20fa909ef3233d20)

Comment: It's a *framework method*. You don't know during compilation which version of the framework you'll actual end up running on (considering e.g. patches and security fixes as well as "allowed" mismatches)

Comment: @KennethK. Does that answer the question? It calls a virtual method that _might_ use reflection depending on how the enum type is generated by the compiler.

Comment: Yeah that answers my question. I guess the answer is "you can't know."

Comment: Also, of course, it shouldn't matter *how* it does it providing it's performing according to its documented behaviour. If it turns out it's e.g. a performance hotspot, it again doesn't matter how it works because you're not going to use it anyway.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever true, but I was asking more out of curiosity than actually trying to solve a problem. But besides, if I can _predict_ a performance hotspot beforehand, that'd be preferable.

Comment: @Jordak If you're unsure and concerned, you could always cache the results somewhere.

Comment: @DStanley they already are cached. The Enum.cs class uses a cache to store names and values per type

Comment: Roughly, yes.  There are two kind of reflection code, the general kind that goes through RuntimeType and the specific kind that uses dedicated CLR helper functions.  The latter uses type info that can retrieved from the internal type representation that the CLR maintains.  The fast kind.  That is what Enum.GetValues() uses, the dedicated CLR helper function is a QCall named GetEnumValuesAnd Names().  It is [located here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/reflectioninvocation.cpp#L2791), in the relectioninvocation.cpp source file.  More than you wanted to know, sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it should. Below is the code which does the job

```
    // This will return enumValues and enumNames sorted by the values.
    private void GetEnumData(out string[] enumNames, out Array enumValues)
    {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.ValueAtReturn<String[]>(out enumNames) != null);
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.ValueAtReturn<Array>(out enumValues) != null);

        FieldInfo[] flds = GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

        object[] values = new object[flds.Length];
        string[] names = new string[flds.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < flds.Length; i++)
        {
            names[i] = flds[i].Name;
            values[i] = flds[i].GetRawConstantValue();
        }

        // Insertion Sort these values in ascending order.
        // We use this O(n^2) algorithm, but it turns out that most of the time the elements are already in sorted order and
        // the common case performance will be faster than quick sorting this.
        IComparer comparer = Comparer.Default;
        for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            int j = i;
            string tempStr = names[i];
            object val = values[i];
            bool exchanged = false;

            // Since the elements are sorted we only need to do one comparision, we keep the check for j inside the loop.
            while (comparer.Compare(values[j - 1], val) > 0)
            {
                names[j] = names[j - 1];
                values[j] = values[j - 1];
                j--;
                exchanged = true;
                if (j == 0)
                    break;
            }

            if (exchanged)
            {
                names[j] = tempStr;
                values[j] = val;
            }
        }

        enumNames = names;
        enumValues = values;
    }
```

Pay attention to **FieldInfo[] flds = GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);** line. It really looks like reflection method.
The method GetFields is abstract

```
 abstract public FieldInfo[] GetFields(BindingFlags bindingAttr);
```

so I'm not sure how it is implemented for enums.